# Cannot figure out what test to use for this series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this series and I am trying to determine if it is *convergent* or *divergent*. I already tried the comparison test and it seems to fail but only perhaps because I am breaking apart the sequence incorrectly.

$$\sum_2^\infty \frac{n+30}{n^2\sqrt n}.$$

Comment: limit comparison test?

Comment: use the universal convergence test

Comment: You can divide top and bottom by $n$, then use direct comparison.

Comment: I triedthe limit  comparison test but perhaps by setting b(subn) as $\frac{n}{n^{2}\sqrt{n}}$ is not correct?

Comment: For limit comparison your $b_n$ is fine. Maybe more  simply observe that the top is $\le 31n$.

Comment: Can you elaborate Andre?

Comment: @Erik to elaborate on Andre's hint, since we are looking only at values of $n\geq 2$ you have $30\leq 30n$ so $n+30\leq 31n$.  Letting $f(n)$ be the expression and being lazy with writing limits on the sum, we have $\sum f(n) \leq \sum \frac{31n}{n^2\sqrt{n}}=31\sum\frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$.  Now, do you recognize anything about the convergence or divergence of the far right expressions?

Comment: Convergent by P-series >1 .

Comment: @Erik And so with all of that, perhaps you could write up your own answer in the space provided below so that this question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should forget about the thirty in the numerator, divide top and bottom by the **n** in the numerator, then by the Direct Comparison Test with the p-series with **p=3/2** it follows that the series converges.

Check out [Paul's Online Notes: Series Strategies](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesStrategy.aspx)